# How to understand `this` inside a normal function and an arrow function?

Tags: javascript

I want to load a remote image to get its height and width but get different result.

Below code gives me correct image height and width

```
img.onload= function() {
                    console.log('image;', this.width, this.height);
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
                };
img.src = url;
```

but I got `undefined` value for height and width if I use arrow function as below:

```
img.onload=() => {
                    console.log('image;', this.width, this.height);
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
                };
img.src = url;
```

Can anyone tell me why I can't get it in arrow function? And how can I get the size in an arrow function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An arrow function does not have its own `this` binding, so it uses the one that it closes over.

To get it, instead define an `event` parameter. and use `event.currentTarget.width`.

```
img.onload = event => {
  console.log('image;', event.currentTarget.width, event.currentTarget.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
};
```